# Express router doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Why this router doesn't work? I executed the route but it doesn't return any response.
Someone can explain to me why this code doesn't work?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get ('/',function(req,resp){
mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var cursor = db.collection('link').find();

    cursor.each( 
        function(doc) { 
            var count = 0;
            var result = '';
                if(count ==0) count++;  result = "<!doctype html><html><head>URLShortener Home page</head><body><h1>In this page you can see the urls have already been shortened using this service<ul>";
                console.log(doc);
                if(doc !==null && count >0) 
                {
                    result +=  "<li>old URL: " + doc.old+"</li>";
                }
                else{
                    result += "</ul></body></html>";
                    resp.end(result);
                }


});

});
})
```

Comment: check your cursor.

Comment: i edited the code. now the router returns a response, but if(doc !==null && count >0) 
                {
                    result +=  "<li>old URL: " + doc.old+"</li>";
                } isn't never executed? Why?

Comment: use whileloop until doc.next() dont use count

Comment: can you write me an example?

Comment: try this cursor.toArray(function(err, doc){
console.log(doc);
})

Comment: let me know if not working

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`cursor.toArray(function(err, doc){ console.log(doc); })`